# MySQL value is true change checked to true

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello I wanna to do somethink like:

MySQL enabled = yes or no.

```
if ($enabled=='yes'){
    <input type="radio" name="MyName" value="yes" checked="checked" />Yes <input type="radio" name="MyName" value="no" />No 
}

if ($enabled=='no'){
    <input type="radio" name="MyName" value="yes" />Yes <input type="radio" name="MyName" value="no" checked="checked" />No
}
```

Is this possible? I know I can use if(), but I wanna other way. Is there other way?

Comment: use  `<?php if($enable == 'yes') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>` to echo the checked status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, it is possible ...
you should use `array` like this:

```
function one(){
<input type="radio" name="MyName" value="yes" checked="checked" />Yes <input type="radio" name="MyName" value="no" />No 
}
function two(){
<input type="radio" name="MyName" value="yes" />Yes <input type="radio" name="MyName" value="no" checked="checked" />No
}

$arr=array(
    'yes'=>'one',
    'no'=>'two'
);

$arr[$enable]();
```